# How to use DSL connection and ethernet Network concurrently

Tags: networking, ethernet, dsl

In my university, we use a dial up network for internet. Apart from that we are also connected with Ethernet network. By this we can access shared folders of other friends. But In windows we did it concurrently. So while I am downloading something in the web (about 1MBps), I can also copy from my friends shared folder at (11MBps).

But In ubuntu 14.04 I have faced this kind of problem, I can not use it concurrently. While using Web, I cannot use ethernet network. At first I have to disconnect DSL connection then connect ethernet connection.

So is there any solution to use them both concurrently like in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in Ubuntu too. There is a detailed description [here](http://aleksz-programming.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-wifi-and-network-cable-at-same.html). I hope you should follow that and see if you can solve your problem.